# Character table of the symmetric group $S_n$ according to James

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, characters

In James, "The representation theory of the symmetric groups" an algorithm is described to produce the character table of a symmetric group. The proof involves the equation (pp. 22,23)

$$\lvert S_\lambda\rvert \lvert S_\nu\rvert \langle \text{ind}_{S_\lambda}^{S_n} 1_{S_\lambda}, \text{ind}_{S_\mu}^{S_n} 1_{S_\mu}\rangle = \sum_{\mu} \frac{n!}{\lvert S_\mu \rvert} \lvert S_\lambda \cap S_\mu \rvert \lvert S_\nu \cap S_\mu\rvert$$

which is verified by first applying Frobenius reciprocity and then getting to the intermediate (apparently equal) term

$$\lvert S_{\lambda} \rvert \sum_{\mu} \text{ind}_{S_\lambda}^{S^n}(g^\mu) \lvert S_\nu \cap S_\mu \rvert$$

(where $g^\mu$ is some element of type $\mu$). Looking at James, Kerber, "The representation theory of the symmetric group" I find that this part of the statement is removed and instead there is a general discussion about the values of $\langle \text{ind}_{S_\lambda}^{S_n} 1_{S_\lambda}, \text{ind}_{S_\mu}^{S_n} 1_{S_\mu}\rangle$. Could someone explain to me, what the status of those few lines in the first book is? Is it easy and I'm just missing something easy? Or does it in fact use more machinery than is available at that point?

Edit: a formulation of the question that does not involve characters is how to see

$$\lvert S_\lambda \backslash S_n / S_\nu \rvert = \frac{\lvert S_n \rvert}{\lvert S_\lambda \rvert \lvert S_\nu \rvert }\sum_{\mu} \frac{1}{\lvert S_\mu \rvert} \lvert S_\lambda \cap S_\mu \rvert \lvert S_\nu \cap S_\mu \rvert\text{.}$$

Edit2: I think he is saying that $\lvert (g^\mu)^{S_n} \cap S_\nu \rvert = \lvert S_\mu \cap S_\nu \rvert$ (the first is the conjugacy class of $g^\mu$ in $S_n$).

**Solution:** In the end this is about handwriting: James writes a gothic S for the symmetric groups and a curly C for conjugacy classes. Just, both of these are little squiggles and I only realize now that they are supposed to be distinct. So every $S_\mu$ has to be a $C_\mu = (g^{\mu})^{S_n}$. I apologize to everyone who spent time on this!

P.S: James himself gets confused about this: The fraction $n!/\lvert C_\mu \rvert$ is the order of the centralizer of $g^\mu$ so the denominator has to be $C_\mu$ rather than $S_\mu$. However, what James writes is very clearly (once you get sensitive to the distinction) an $S_\mu$.

Comment: Is Mackey's formula mentioned in the intermediate lines?

Comment: No, that's the thing. It appears that it should be used but he specifically does not. He applies Frobenius reciprocity (which would also be the first step toward Mackey) but then he writes the resulting scalar product out with $1_{S_\mu}$ as a sum. Sorry, I should probably add that intermediate step to the question.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: It's certainly not mentioned but mabye it is Mackey's formula after all (and then some more steps so it's not apparent).

Comment: Is the sum ranging over all partitions $\mu$ of $n$ or over all compositions $\mu$ of $n$ ?

Comment: Also, which part of James pp. 22-23 are you referring to?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Partitions. It's a sequence of displayed equations around the page break: the last three lines on page 22 and the first few on page 23.

Comment: And $S_\mu$ is the Young subgroup (so, in particular, $S_{\left(n\right)} = S_n$ and $S_{\left(1,1,\ldots,1\right)} = \left\{\operatorname{id}\right\}$)? In this case, this is false for $n = 2$ and $\lambda = \nu = \left(1,1\right)$ unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: You are saying the left hand side is 1 while the right hand side is 1 + 1, yes? So perhaps there is a restriction on \mu (that \nu has to dominate \mu?). (I suppose it's even more apparent in the formulation of edit2: the conjugacy class of (1 2) does not meet $S_\nu$ at all, so $\mu = (2)$ should not be allowed.)

Comment: I'm talking about the equality in your first Edit; conjugacy classes don't even appear there.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: right, there the right hand side is not even an integer if $\mu = (2)$ is allowed. So I think it's safe to assume that if $n = 2$ and $\lambda = \nu = (1,1)$ then $\mu$ is supposed to only range over $(1,1)$.

Comment: Hah, I got confused by James's Fraktur too. Someone should really republish the book in 21th century typesetting.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: In any case, thanks for pointing out that it doesn't work on small examples! After making apologies about your counterexample I looked at $\mu = (2,1)$ and $\nu = (3)$ and there it just made no sense at all.